# Missing Expression: Server error number: 003000 (EOCINativeException) [FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, expression, ora-00936

```
  SELECT
        UserId,
        FirstName,
        MiddleName,
        LastName,
        Gender,
        Email,
        Student,
        Password,
        Major,
        Ethnicity,
        Class,
        Academic_Program,
        LTI_User_ID,
        SSO_UID,
        Act1,
        Act2,
        Act3,
        Act4,
        ActCom,
        Satv,
        Satm,
        SatSum


  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SPRIDEN_PIDM AS UserID,
        SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME AS FirstName,
        SPRIDEN_MI AS MiddleName,
        SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME AS LastName,
        SPBPERS_SEX AS Gender,
        HUSTUDENT.CK_EMAIL (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Email,
        'student' AS Student,
        'password' AS Password,
        SGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_1 AS Major,
        SPBPERS_ETHN_CDE AS Ethnicity,
        F_CLASS_CALC_FNC (A.SGBSTDN_PIDM,
                          A.SGBSTDN_LEVL_CODE,
                          SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE) AS Class,
        'ACADEMICPROGRAM' AS Academic_Program,
        'LTIUSERID' AS LTI_User_ID,
        'SSOUID' AS SSO_UID,
        SCHEV.CK_ACT1 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Act1,
        SCHEV.CK_ACT2 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Act2,
        SCHEV.CK_ACT3 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Act3,
        SCHEV.CK_ACT4 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Act4,
        SCHEV.CK_ACT5 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS ActCom,
        SCHEV.CK_SATV1 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Satv,
        SCHEV.CK_SATM1 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) AS Satm,
        SCHEV.CK_SATV1 (SPRIDEN_PIDM) + SCHEV.CK_SATM1 (K.SORTEST_PIDM) AS SatSum


  FROM   SPRIDEN,
     SPBPERS,
     SGBSTDN,
         SFRSTCR


  WHERE
               AND SPRIDEN_CHANGE_IND IS NULL
               AND SPRIDEN_PIDM = SPBPERS_PIDM
               AND SPRIDEN_PIDM = SGBSTDN_PIDM
               AND SPRIDEN_PIDM = SFRSTCR_PIDM
               AND SFRSTCR_TERM_CODE = :TERM


               AND :Button_Run_query IS NOT NULL)


  ORDER BY SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: You have `WHERE` followed by `AND` - there should be a condition between, or you should remove that `AND`. If you paste the code into a client and try to run it, it will probably tell you where the problem is; just pasting into SQL Developer will highlight the stray `AND` with a red squiggle under it, and running it will report the line and character number.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try moving the closing parenthesis that is after `Button_run_query is not null` to the end of your `ORDER BY ...SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME`. If the order by clause is missing then the closing parenthesis is fine there. But the ORDER By FIELDS are using the inner query fields so you need to use the closing parenthesis to close the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple things I was seeing until I took the above code and put it in Notepad++. As I was splitting it out, I saw that I had WHERE AND, so I fixed that and then I also had to change the order by to LastName and FirstName instead of the actual names out of the file.